# Unary minus on squared number

Tags: exponentiation

According to algebra as I know it, $-2^2 = 4$, but most calculators expand this to $-2 * 2 = -4$, which yields a different answer.  This is because of the order of precedence.  In traditional math, I've seen that the unary operator is applied before exponents.  This is not the case for calculators.

I have two questions:

1) What caused this difference and why does it persist?
2) Is one method "more accurate" than the other and why?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by "traditional math"? Perhaps give an example of an instance where a unary operation is applied before exponents?

Comment: $-2^2=-4$, not $4$. (unless you meant $(-2)^2=4$)

Comment: @Sujaan: If I wrote $(-2)^2$, then the statement would read "according to algebra as I know it, $(-2)^2 = 4$", which would be pointless because calculators evaluate to the same result *once you remove the ambiguity*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point at issue, here, is whether $-2^2$ indicates the square of the opposite of $2$ (which is $4$), or whether it indicates the opposite of the square of $2$ (which is $-4$). As a rule, we indicate the former by $(-2)^2,$ and the latter by $-2^2.$ This is because of the order of operations. $-2^2=-4$ because exponentiation occurs before multiplication (by $-1$, in this case), while $(-2)^2=4$ because the multiplication *inside the parentheses* takes place before the exponentiation.

Why would we do this, though? It isn't just convention. If we consider the general case, with an arbitrary real $x,$ and forget all rules of precedence except parentheses, then there are two possible meanings for $-x^2,$ namely:

- $(-x)^2$
- $-(x^2)$

In the first case, this is simply $x^2,$ so not only was there no real need to write the parentheses, there wasn't a need to write the $-$ sign! However, we'd like to have a way to talk about a perfect square's opposite, which the first interpretation quite simply won't allow. That's why we take the second interpretation of $-x^2,$ and use parentheses when we need to square a number's opposite.

Ultimately, the order of operations is done for precisely such reasons: to let us have flexibility enough to say what we mean *without* needing a whole bunch of parentheses.

Comment: I would say it differently.  There are two expressions, $-(x^2)$ and $(-x)^2$.  The first is often needed, but the second is equal to $x^2$, which we would usually write instead of $(-x)^2$.  Therefore we save ink (and thought) by declaring $-x^2$ to mean $-(x^2)$.

Comment: @GEdgar: That's a good point--and one I was working on explaining when you commented. Thanks!